# WebGL: glDrawElements exceeding vertex bounds

Tags: javascript, webgl

I've built a 2-D grid in WebGL. It has 5 columns, and 24 rows. Each "cell" in my grid is four vertices, and six indices:

So for each cell, I do:

```
var addCell = function(x, y, w, h, colorArray) {
    len = vertices.length;

    vertices.push(x, y, zIndex);
    vertices.push(x, y - h, zIndex);
    vertices.push(x + w, y - h, zIndex);
    vertices.push(x + w, y, zIndex);

    Array.prototype.push.apply(colors, colorArray);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(colors, colorArray);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(colors, colorArray);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(colors, colorArray);

    indices.push(len, len + 1, len + 2);
    indices.push(len, len + 2, len + 3);
}
```

where x and y are the coordinates of the cell, and "colors" is a four-element array specifying rgba. So I create the first row from left to right, then the second row, and so on. When I create my index buffer, I do:

```
indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

And when I draw my scene, I say:

```
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

When I do this, it only renders the first 12 3/4 rows (of 24). This is because each cell is 4 vertices (adjacent cells do not share vertices). So the first 12+ rows contain:
12.75 * 5 * 4 = 255 <- the max value of GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE.

So to me this was an obvious outcome given my type choice. I thought naturally the solution was to change to gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT and also change my creation of the buffer to:

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

However this results in "glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0".

I've stared at my index/vertex-building code for a while trying to see if I'm adding an index that points to a vertex element that doesn't exist. I don't see anything wrong with that code, which makes me think it has something to do with the *type* I'm choosing. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `UNSIGNED_SHORT` you're on the right track. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21212640/2378910) on what the new error you get means: there's an index referencing a vertex that doesn't exist.

This is because your `len` is off. Each index references a vertex, consisting of 3 values each.  So index 0 references the first 3 values, index 1 the second 3, etc.

Changing

```
len = vertices.length;
```

to

```
len = vertices.length / 3;
```

should fix it.

Comment: Ah, of course. I actually needed to divide by 3 (each vertex consists of 3 points). Thank you very much!